# JRebel for IntelliJ and gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, embedded-jetty, jrebel

In my app I use multiple modules around 15 of them. I am unable to configure JRebel. Please help as I have referred many URL's all so confusing.

I use IntelliJ, gradle and inbuilt jetty server. Also my app will be a jar acrhive. I manually right-clicked against each module and selected 'generate rebel.xml'. Then I clicked on the 'debug with JRebel' option. I made some changes to my page and clicked Reload (in firefox). BUt nothing happened.

Please help!!

Comment: When you made the changes, have you actually compiled the changed class? The paths in rebel.xml files are those that JRebel monitors for the changes, meaning the new versions of the compiled classes should appear in those folders.

Comment: same issue here. https://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/jrebel-gradle-intellij-rebel-xml-files-have-wrong-build-path/#post-64099